# Different Encodings in ServletRequest Parameters

Tags: java, servlets, encoding

[ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) only affects Parameters submitted in the body of the request. It does not affect URL-Parameters.

JBoss is encoding URL-Parameters with ISO-8859-1 as default and this can only be changed [server-wide](https://community.jboss.org/message/643825#643825).

[ServletRequest.getParameterMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) is returning a Map filled with both - form-data from the request-body and URL-Parameters. So if I recive form-data endoded with UTF-8 *and* URL-Parameters I will find different endodings in the parameter-map.

What I'm doing now is parsing [HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) with [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) and overwriting every parameter in the requestParameterMap which comes from the queryString.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?